# MySQL correct statement for "update all rows where column > number"?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'images' with a few rows of image names and a value for their position (order which they will appear on site).

```
id      name       position
1       dog.png    3
2       cat.png    1
3       snake.png  2
```

What im trying to do is decrement all position column values if they are above a specific value.

For example, if 'cat' is to be deleted, i want to find all rows with a position higher (would be snake and dog) and decrement their position values by 1. I need an SQL statement for

"update all 'position' columns where 'position' > 'value'"

I know i need to get the 'position' of the image to be deleted, and set this to 'value' before updating the rest of the rows with higher position columns. But, I'm not sure how to create the SQL statement for the rest of:

"update all 'position' columns where 'position' > 'value'"

I'm not sure whether i would need one or two queries for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following simple `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE images SET position = position - 1 WHERE position > 1
```

You can also use the following to `UPDATE` the images and `DELETE` the specific image:

```
-- first update the other images
UPDATE images t1, (SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = 2) t2 SET t1.position = t1.position - 1 WHERE t1.position > t2.position

-- now you can delete the image
DELETE FROM images WHERE id = 2
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a748f63c973fe8bfd66f094b91049f5)

Inspired by [Tim Biegeleisen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56391843/3840840) you can use the following `UPDATE` to close the gaps after deleting one or more images. In this case you have to use MySQL 8.0 or later (for [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)):

```
UPDATE images t1, 
  (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position) rn FROM images) t2 
SET t1.position = t2.rn
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

In this case you can also delete multiple images like this:

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb36dc11641c5da0dfdbf2bb14a3627b)

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to recommend *against* doing the update after deleting records.  Instead, just use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the effective position of each record, e.g.

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position) position
FROM yourTable;
```

Deleting rows will not change the relative order which exists between all records in the table.

If you are not using MySQL 8+, then you can easily enough simulate row number using user variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a trigger :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER position_after_delete
AFTER DELETE
   ON images FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- Update position 
   UPDATE images SET position = position - 1 WHERE position > OLD.position

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```